# How to add capabilities for editor type user to access admin section

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, capabilities

How to add capabilities for editor type of the user. After login from admin side editor type of the user can access certain woocommerce product from admin dashboard.
Only user can see some assign product listing and user can edit assign product. I did product assignment job at my end and stored user id in corresponding to post Id in postmeta table. 
How to add rule and capabilites user can see and edit woocommerce assign products. I want this job using theme function how to do. Please give me solution about same. 
Looking forward to reply

Comment: That's a lot of custom functionality to develop. There are plugins available that provide this type of thing and it may be easier to maintain than a custom solution. Look for role management plugins (as specific recommendations are off-topic here).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We want that functionality using theme functions file how to do. How to give capabilities to editor type user.we have some restrictions to use plugin. That's why we want use theme functions m

Comment: That's a big question, bigger than someone can answer here. You can always look into existing plugins and see how they accomplish the goal, then build something similar into the theme. Or if you haven't considered an `mu-plugin` that might solve it as well.

Comment: Can you please let me know best plugin which full fill my above requirement.?.  Because I am new in WordPress.

Comment: Sorry, that's considered off-topic. I would suggest looking into Facebook WP Plugin groups. There are some dedicated to that purpose who may be able to help better - or again, just search for role management plugins. :)